# Inheritance of Action in AsyncController

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, async-await, asynccontroller

I have a base AsyncController

```
BaseController : AsyncController
{ 
    [Authorize("Admin")]
    public virtual async Task<ActionResult> SomeMethod()
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

How it is correct to inheritance and override **SomeMethod**?

```
UserController : BaseController
{ 
    [Authorize("User")]
    public override Task<ActionResult> SomeMethod()
    {
        return base.SomeMethod()
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
UserController : BaseController
{ 
    [Authorize("User")]
    public override async Task<ActionResult> SomeMethod()
    {
        return await base.SomeMethod()
    }
}
```

P.S. Sorry for my english

Comment: Your two controllers are not related. Is `UserController` suppose to inherit from `BaseController`?

Comment: yes, `UserController` is inherited from `BaseController`

Comment: What version of MVC are you using. `AsyncController` was provided for backward compatibility with ASP.NET MVC 3. Otherwise you can simply use `Controller` ie: `public class BaseController : Controller`.

Comment: I use ASP.NET MVC 5

Comment: Ok then use `Controler` not `AsyncController` as for inheritance of your controller, it doesn't matter you can use either one and it should work. It is more of an implementation detail.

Comment: @Nkosi is right. If you aren't doing anything in your overridden method that requires further awaiting, then your second option is best (just bubble up the task as is).  If you are doing further operations that require awaiting, then your first option is best.

Comment: Microsoft recommends suffixing base (not prefixing) for naming conventions `ControllerBase`.

Comment: Just one tip: if the compiler isn't complaining (no errors and no warnings), then it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

`SomeMethod()` is defined within your `BaseController` class. Therefore child classes should inherit from `BaseController` rather than `AsyncController`. To override the method, just add `virtual` keyword into the definition.

```
BaseController : AsyncController
{ 
    [Authorize("Admin")]
    public virtual async Task<ActionResult> SomeMethod()
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

Inheritance and override

```
UserController : BaseController
{ 
    [Authorize("User")]
    public override Task<ActionResult> SomeMethod()
    {
        return base.SomeMethod()
    }
}
```

Also I have noticed something odd in your `Authorize` attributes. If the base method is allow to Admin only and the child method is allow to User only, then you most likely end up being unable to execute the base method from the child class.